# clang, lto, prevent function removal

Tags: c, clang, lto

I am compiling a project with a modified version of **clang** using link time optimization (**lto**) and **O2** optimization level. O0 and O1 are doing fine, but sadly O2 **removes some calls** to functions. Is there a way to tell the optimization to omit specific functions?
I have already tried using `volatile` variables as well as `__attribute__ ((optimize("0")))` without success.

Solutions only available directly on llvm IR level are also welcome.

*Edit*: Maybe I should explain the situation with a little more detail.
The modified clang adds calls to a custom runtime lib which is build together with clang. 
Some of this inserted calls get optimized away.

Answer (score 4):

I believe  `__attribute(used)__` (GCC) or `llvm.used` (LLVM) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `__attribute__((noinline))` will keep the so-designated functions from disappearing. You could also prevent it globally with `-fno-inline`.

Comment: Marking the runtime functions with __attribute__((noinline)) has no effect :(

Comment: Hmm - maybe LTO doesn't respect that stuff. I guess it's quite possible; the C attributes might be long gone by the time the linker gets around to seeing things.